# Детальная информация на новой активности

Tags: java, android, kotlin, onclicklistener

Нужна помощь, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии для каждой ячейки RecyclerView после ее нажатие и перехода на новую активность с помощью onClick ,и на этой самой активности появлялось название объекта и детальная информация , если есть задумки как это можно сделать на Kotlin без базы данных(название у меня получилось перенести с помощью intent.putExtra)

[Фотографии кода](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ot86FbmbMo2yVSGzKhhWWCQE74b_LEqU?usp=sharing)

```
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),onClick {
    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var item: ArrayList<Item>? = null
    private var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: Adapter? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.item_list)
    //количество grid элементов в строчке
    gridLayoutManager =
            GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 2, 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
    recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)

    item = ArrayList()
    item = setItem()
    //установка адаптера
    adapter = Adapter(item!!,this)
    recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
    item_list.adapter=adapter
    }
private fun setItem(): ArrayList<Item> {
    //добавление элементов в RecyclerView
    var arrayList: ArrayList<Item> = ArrayList()
    arrayList.add(Item(R.drawable.koscmos, "A Latter"))
    arrayList.add(Item(R.drawable.teatr, "B Latter"))
    arrayList.add(Item(R.drawable.bridge, "C Latter"))
    return arrayList
}

override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"id" +position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    //переход на новую активность с переносом названия в эту активность
    val intent= Intent(this,secondAct::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("name", item?.get(position)?.name)
    startActivity(intent)
     }
    }
```

Адаптер:

```
class Adapter(var arrayList: ArrayList<Item>, private val onClick: onClick) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<Holder>() {

//Установка холдера
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
    val viewHolder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false)
    return Holder(viewHolder)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return arrayList.size
}

 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
 //установка элементов для onClick
    val item: Item = arrayList[position]
    holder.icons.setImageResource(item.icons!!)
    holder.titles.text = item.name
    holder.icons.setOnClickListener {
        onClick.onItemClick(position)
    }
    holder.titles.setOnClickListener {
        onClick.onItemClick(position)
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1232009/420098/edit)). Снять порчу с кода по фотографии тут вряд ли смогут ))

Comment: Сделайте `Item : Serializable` и передавайте его целиком:  `intent.putExtra("item", item?.get(position))`